# My dictionary wp app in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8.1

I want when writing the word frequently.. be repeated again

like this:
textbox1 "France - Jordan - France"...
and show me "Paris - Amman - Paris"

***but in this code showing me just a one time "Paris - Amman"***

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dictionary.Add("France", "Paris");
        dictionary.Add("England", "London");
        dictionary.Add("Jordan", "Amman");

        textbox2.Text = "";
        if (textbox1.Text.Contains("France"))
        {
            string value = dictionary["France"];
            textbox2.Text += value;
        }

        if (textbox1.Text.Contains("England"))
        {
            string value = dictionary["England"];
            textbox2.Text += value;
        }

        if (textbox1.Text.Contains("Jordan"))
        {
            string value = dictionary["Jordan"];
            textbox2.Text += value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be in a looping structure, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `France - Jordan - France` You need display `Paris - Amman - Paris`; So your code should be

```
    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("France"))
    {
        string value = dictionary["France"];
        textbox2.Text += value;
    }

    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("Jordan"))
    {
        string value = dictionary["Jordan"];
        textbox2.Text += value;
    }

    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("France"))
    {
        string value = dictionary["France"];
        textbox2.Text += value;
    }
```

Your below `if` condition will be `false` since the said string doesn't contain the word `England`

```
    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("England"))
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dictionary is small (less than a few hundreds elements), you can make a copy of your string, then replace all occurrences:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    dictionary.Add("France", "Paris");
    dictionary.Add("England", "London");
    dictionary.Add("Jordan", "Amman");

    var result = textbox1.Text;

    foreach (var entry in dictionary)
    {
        result.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }

    textbox2.Text = result;
}
```

The good side of this solution is that you keep the exact formatting of your original string. For instance, if your input was `***France***, $$$Jordan$$$`, your output will be `***Paris***, $$$Amman$$$`. The drawback is that it executes slower than a targeted search, like in Joel Legaspi Enriquez's answer. But if your dictionary isn't big, it shouldn't make any visible difference (a few milliseconds tops).

Answer (score 0):

What happen is that `Text.Contains()` only reports if it contains that text, it does not count how many occurrences it has. You can try to split the string (if you have any specific character or string that can be used as splitter such as `-` then count how many occurrences you have then loop and rebuild your result.

Or you can use this to count the number of occurrences in a string (but this is specific for what key you are looking for):

```
string text = "France - France - France";
int count = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, "France").Count;
```

A simple approach as mentioned using `Split()` then looping would be:

```
string[] values = textbox1.Text.Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach( string value in values)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(value))
    {
        textbox2.Text += dictionary[value];
        textbox2.Text += " - "; //Mind that you need to remove this on your last element.
    }
}
```